# On Flutter, why is the State a Widget itselt?

Tags: flutter

I'm getting started with flutter and something doesn't make any sense for me.

I understand the need for `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget`. In fact, in React we have the exact same concepts. `build` in Flutter is `render` in React and `StatelessWidget` is a React Functional Component whereas a `StatefulWidget` is a `React.Component`. So far, so good.

The problem is that, unlike React, on Flutter, the `StatefulWidget` is not a Widget that happens to have a state. It is actually just a class that has a `createState()` that creates a state and, **now the part that I don't understand, the `State<T>` class is the actual Widget** because `State` has `build` .

For me, it would make much more sense if the `StatefulWidget` structure would be like:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget<TState> {
  // Here, the state parameter DOES NOT EXIST. This is pseudo-code.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, TState state) {
  }
}
```

This way, the `build` function creates different `Elements` based on the current state. This would be much more React like.

Why was Flutter implemented this way? Why is the `State` class actually the Widget and not the `StatefulWidget` itself?

Comment: `State` is not a widget, it just contains a `build` method.

Comment: State and Widget have different lifecycles

Comment: @RémiRousselet if a class contains a method returning exclusively a widget (thus becoming a factory), it can be treated as a widget generator function. That's where the OP's frustration comes from. I share the sentiment, so far makes no sense.

Comment: @ElijahSaounkine Widgets are objects created inside `build`. `State` is never created inside `build`, there's a completely different life-cycle for that.

Comment: @RémiRousselet regardless of the lifecycle, I replied to your earlier comment on the fact that "`State` is not a widget". In the eyes of a functional programming developer, `Widget a` and `Widget a()` are very similar concepts: functions are reasoned about as values. And it doesn't matter what other structures you wrap around functions - call them classes or state. On the other hand, dependency on the lifecycle, is a weak excuse for poor design (just to clarify, I'm not saying that flutter design is poor, haven't got that far yet).